# What does the following mean

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the meaning of the following sentence taken from a lesson in by Jenny Tabakoff. 
"I have yet to come to terms with the video cassette recorder"

Answer (score 1):

*to come to terms with...*  literally means "to enter into a binding legal agreement with", but the locution is used figuratively to mean

gotten used to the idea of

get along peacefully with

figured out how to use

when it is used in the context of new technology.

If someone were to say this of the video cassette recorder today in 2016, it would suggest that they are very far behind the times.  If it was said when the VCR was new technology, it would indicate that they are not yet comfortable with the new technology.